# Is it bad to have too many Kernel modules?

Tags: linux-kernel, performance, kernel-modules

I'm trying to compile a Linux kernel to debug an issue I have on Arch Linux, and I was configuring modules, but I didn't know what a lot of the stuff was so I left them on.

If this kernel works I plan to keep it, but would all those extra modules slow the system down or will it load up only when they are needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you won't notice any performance improvement (assuming you build your kernel with the modules you actaully require), there is some benefit in removing unneeded modules: first, it can significantly reduce the compile time and secondly, it will reduce the size of the final kernel.

Creating a `.config` with `make localmodconfig` is a good way to get your feet wet. See the Arch Wiki for the [traditional compilation approach](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Compilation/Traditional).

Comment: As long as they are modules and not built-in, it won't increase the size of the resulting image, but the overall size would be larger.

Comment: Note that in general it tends to be safer to have a module you don't need than it is to decide to "streamline" your kernel build only to find out after a reboot that you forgot a driver that it turns out you *did* need...

Comment: The kernel can be loaded to ram faster by the boot loader, but the time that it spend loading modules will produce a slower startup.

Answer (score 2):

The modules are loaded as needed: don't worry, as there's no slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to install 4.16-rc4+, I discovered a pitfall of selecting too many modules while configuring the kernel.

The resulting `initramfs` image, which seems to include all modules by default, is 358MB in size, which is *way* too big to fit in my `/boot` partition.

I am now on a quest to discover what magic is needed to tell `update-initramfs` to ignore particular modules or trees in `/lib/modules/kernel-version`.

Comment: Set `MODULES=dep` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` to reduce the number modules in your initramfs.

Comment: @Declan please don’t be so enthusiastic with your back-ticks — you got the “s” wrong in `update-initramfs` there, and versions and file-sizes aren’t easier to read when formatted as code IMO.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt Thank you! I had figured out that `MODULES=dep` was relevant, but not where to set it.